# Working with Samsung Smart TV Emulator (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to create a Samsung Smart TV application. I have the SDK installed on my windows VM (via VMWare) and it all looks fine until you go to run the application in the emulator. It does nothing.. I even tried starting the emulators manually and here are the respect errors:

## [2011]Samsung TV Emulator(2.5.1)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2011_v2.5\bin\Emulator2.exe

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please set the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

## [2012]Samsung TV Emulator(3.5.2)

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application.
```

## [2013]Samsung TV Emulator4

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application.
```

### Extra Details

I'm running Windows 7 Pro on Mac OS using VMWare Fusion 5.

So I'm not sure what to do at this point. Is there a work-around?

Comment: Did you install the proper version of SDK?SDK for windows XP/Linux?

Comment: I installed the Windows 7 SDK from here: http://www.samsungdforum.com/devtools/sdkdownload - note that you have to sign up first before you can download it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same trouble.

Install  vcredist_x86.EXE http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26347

Exactly vcredist_x86.EXE 2.6 MB

Emulator will work on Windows 7 x64. Checked.